# Mastodon: How can you authenticate an app without a user token?

Tags: oauth-2.0

My understanding of oauth2 (in the context of Mastodon) is that the user registers their client with a Mastodon instance and receives client secrets which are then used to craft an authentication uri, which the user visits and retrieves an auth code, which is used with the secrets to request the final auth token. That token is used to sign authenticated requests via request headers.

I noticed that Mastodon does not require a user to verify an application's oauth2 credentials.

https://docs.joinmastodon.org/api/rest/apps/#get-api-v1-apps-verify-credentials

**How is it possible to send any authenticated request without having a user authenticated?**

Answer (score 0):

From OAuth 2.0 point of view, users do not require to validate application credentials. Application credentials belongs to application and must be protected from any third party, which include end users.

OAuth 2.0 is for authorization, or in other words access delegation. When end user use your application, he/she is allowing your application to consume his/her resources. So it is application's duty to retrieve, store, use and protect credentials.

Please read more about [clients (applications) in OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2).

One more thing,

> That token is used to sign authenticated requests via request headers

This understanding is incorrect. Once application receive tokens, they will be simply passed through headers to OAuth protected endpoint (ex:- Mastodon API). This is highlighted in [their documentation](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/api/authentication/)

> Once you have the access token, add the HTTP header Authorization: Bearer ... to any API call.

Read more on it from [RFC6750 - The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)

Comment: In Mastodon there are thousands of servers (instances). From what I understand the user authenticates the app directly instead of the app authenticating itself with thousands of servers and hiding its keys from the user. Perhaps someone can clear this up. Is my app supposed to register itself with thousands of servers and then provide its own auth management server? I am concerned this is anti-pattern to Mastodon infrastructure.

Comment: I was not aware there was a difference between `That token is used to sign authenticated requests via request headers` and `Once application receive tokens, they will be simply passed through headers to OAuth protected endpoint`.

Comment: I think this is explained in their docs , *Mastodon is federated, therefore you can’t be expected to manually register your application on all potential servers your users might want to login on. For this reason, there is an open app registration API, so obtaining OAuth 2 credentials for OAuth 2 authorization can be automated.

Make sure that you allow your users to specify the domain they want to connect to before login. Use that domain to acquire a client id/secret for OAuth 2 and then proceed with normal OAuth 2 also using that domain to build the URLs.*